# "Cannot call method 'call' of null" even though the variable is defined (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm getting the error

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of null
```

in Chrome.  After opening the console, setting to catch uncaught exceptions, and reloading the page, it stops on the following line (minified->prettified code):

```
return this instanceof Q && (b = null != (d = this.getO()) ? d.id : void 0, 0 <= L.call(null != (f = null != c ? "function" === typeof c.get ? c.get("foo") : void 0 : void 0) ? f : [], b))
```

The only instance of `call` in that line is at `L.call(...)`.  Looking at `Scope Variables`, I see no instance of `L` in `Local`.  In `Closure`, I see:

```
L: function indexOf() { [native code] }
  arguments: null
  caller: null
  length: 1
  name: "indexOf"
  __proto__: function Empty() {}
```

As expected, it's defined and is a function.  Inspection of `__proto__` reveals a `call` method.

Further, the console reflects the state shown in `Scope Variables`:

```
> L
function indexOf() { [native code] }
> L.call
function call() { [native code] }
> L.call([], b) // This is what it is getting called with
-1
```

And copying the offending line (minus the `return`) runs as expected.

```
> this instanceof Q && (b = null != (d = this.getO()) ? d.id : void 0, 0 <= L.call(null != (f = null != c ? "function" === typeof c.get ? c.get("foo") : void 0 : void 0) ? f : [], b))
false
```

I can only reproduce this behavior in our production environment.  It happens fairly sporadically, with no pattern I've been able to find.  We've neither observed nor gotten a report of it happening in any browser other than Chrome.  I'm running `Chrome 25.0.1364.172`, and have logs of this error in `Chrome 25.0.1364.152`.

This happens partway through a long chunk of javascript (there's a visible pause of a second or so in the animations while it runs).  Running it on reduced data sets does not reproduce it.

Does anyone have any debugging tips and/or information on reasons the console could be out of sync with the script in this way?

Edit:  I searched the minified source for the variable `L`, but there are only two places it is set to anything other than `[].indexOf`, and they are both definitely out of scope when I hit this line.

The same problem occurs in `Chrome Canary 27.0.1440.0`, but on a different line.  The situation is otherwise the same: the variable `L` is defined but `L.call(...)` throws a `TypeError`.

Comment: "Does anyone have any debugging tips" Get the unminified source.

Comment: @PeeHaa I have it, but as I said, the bug doesn't reproduce outside of production conditions (which includes minification).

Comment: Have you tried running on production with the unminified version?

Comment: @PeeHaa Deploying unminified js to production would be a last resort, at best.  Do you suspect the culprit is our minifier?

Comment: Dunno. But that's what I would try. You could even only serve the non minified one for your own ip

Comment: @PeeHaa I should add that I can't even reproduce this in our staging environment, which also uses minified code.